# Can load csv but not JSON in d3

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to add a few charts to an intranet site to prove the usefulness of d3.  The problem I seem to have is being able to load tsv files but not being able to load json files.

Publishing is through FrontPage. I've copy and pasted the examples below into their own .asp pages, since that is what other pages are. I've copied the style into the head of the html, and the script into the body of the html. The tsv and json files and web pages are next to each other on the staging and the production server.

This example copied into my own page works ok: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

This example copied into my own page returns an error on page load: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Could this be a code problem, or is it possible that my work server doesn't allow json files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean opening the examples by clicking on the links works for the former but not for the latter? Or have you adapted the examples to run locally? Please provide a [mcve] and a detailed description of when and how the problem surfaces.

Comment: I've adapted the examples to run locally, just with copy and paste. Edited for more information.

Comment: The title says you're trying to load a csv but you have a tsv file on the server - have you tried using d3.tsv?

Comment: @Adam-Pearce csv or tsv work, but json does not. What I really want to know is, is it possible to block json from being found?

Comment: No idea. Does that json exist if you navigate to it directly?

Comment: My system administrator got back to me, he add json to the MIME type. Sorry for the goose chase.